# System shuts down even if inhibitor is present

Tags: debian, gnome, systemd

Debian 8.7 / Lenovo T460s / Gnome 3.14.1

I'd like to prevent my notebook from sleep and / or shutdown when running a backup (in the background). I use:
`systemd-inhibit --who=obnam --why="running a backup" obnam backup`

The lock is set (I verified it using `systemd-inhibit --list`) and prevents shutting down the system using `sudo shutdown`.

When using the Gnome "power-button" (in the top right menu) and selecting "Power Off", the lock seems to be ignored and my system, you guess it, shuts down and switches off power.

[image: screenshot showing the "Power Off" button]

### How can I make gnome respect the inhibitor set?

Comment: [The owner of an inhibitor can always ignore his own inhibitor, but not the inhibitors of other users. That is intended behaviour.](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66321)

Comment: Poettering: "The idea for this is that desktop environments check for inhibitors on logout manually, show a nice UI, and offer an "override" button if the inhibitors could be overriden." - am I the only one thinking its ridicoulous that even GNOME doesn't implement this? Come on RedHat!

Comment: I know (I agree with you) but that was not the point of my comment...

Comment: Naa, I didn't take it like that :-)   I'm just amazed at how RH fails to create benefits for the user from systemd + GNOME...